# Запустить другой exe из node js

Tags: node.js, exe, electron

Как запустить другой exe файл, который находится в другом каталоге через node js? Спасибо.

Comment: Тут перечислены возможные варианты: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const filePath = './vodolaz/bober.exe';
require('child_process').execFile(filePath);
```

если exe файл требует конфиг в своей папке, попробуйте сначала перейти в нее, затем запустить файл

```
const cp = require('child_process')
cp.exec('cd ./test/');
cp.execFile('putty.exe');
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но есть проблема. Когда я запускаю 1 программу таким образом, я получаю ошибку: "Configuration file was not found" (При обычном запуске, программа работает нормально). Из-за чего может возникать эта ошибка?

Comment: Он пытается найти конфиг в папке с js скриптом, надо сначала перейти в папку с exe файлом, а потом запустить его. Добавил в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо. Начало работать!